# helper class not found in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have create Helpers folder inside app, then I have created php file amchelpers.php  ---> app/Helpers/amchelpers.php

amchelpers.php code:

```
<?php namespace App;

   class AmcHelper {
      static function displayString($string){
          return $string;
      }
  }
```

then added these lines to composer.json

```
"files": [
       "app/Helpers/amchelpers.php"
    ]
```

then run this command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

then added 'Helper'    => app_path() . '\Helpers\AmcHelper' to aliases array in config/app.php file.

in my controller I have below action (this action defined in route.php):

```
use Helper;

class UserController extends Controller {
   public function displayMyString(){  
         echo Helper::displayString('Hello');
   }
}
```

when run the page http://localhost:8080/easy_marketing/public/displayMyString

I Got:

```
ErrorException in compiled.php line 6367: Class 'C:\wamp\www\easy_marketing\app\Helpers\AmcHelper' not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have written `user Helper` instead of `use Helper`

**or**

another way to achieve this is

Laravel 5 App directory is autoloaded by default with its folder, what you have to take care is add namespace followed by directory name,

so directory structure is App --> Helpers

so your name space must include App\Helpers

try following code

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

   class AmcHelper {
      static function displayString($string){
          return $string;
      }
  }
```

and when you are using this class in another class write this after namespace declaration

```
use App\Helpers\AmcHelper as Helper;


class UserController extends Controller {
   public function displayMyString(){  
         echo Helper::displayString('Hello');
   }
}
```

Comment: got: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\users\Helper' not found

Comment: you have to write  `use App\Helpers\AmcHelper as Helper`